# Storing sockets in GLib hash table

Tags: glib

I have a server app in C; I need to keep track of a vast number of sockets simultaneously (client session data). I don't want to reinvent the wheel and just saw that GLib comes with a hash table implementation. Can a GLib hash table safely be used for what I want to do? Is there anything I should be aware of? Thanks!

Comment: I just came across uthash. Anything beneficial about uthash as far as my use case goes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use GHashTable a lot, both with provided and custom equal/hashing functions, and have nothing but praise for it. Lean and fast implementation with very little overhead. The flexibility it offers in grabbing all keys and/or values as separate GLists, and providing custom free-functions for them is also very useful. Go for it.